# Excel/VBA "CELL" - Variable Not Defined?

Tags: excel, vba

"For Each Cell In rng" is throwing a debug error which I'm blown away. It's saying the word Cell is "Variable Not Defined", it's an inherit variable why would I have to define it? So confused, thanks!

```
lr = GetLastRow(ActiveSheet.Name, 1)
Set rng = Range(Cells(1, ActiveCell.column), Cells(lr, ActiveCell.column))
For Each Cell In rng
    If Cell.Value <> "" And InStr(Cell.Value, "*") > 0 Then
        Cell.Value = Left(Cell.Value, InStr(Cell.Value, "*") - 1)
    End If
Next Cell
```

Comment: `Dim Cell As Range`. Not sure what you mean by "inherit variable".

Comment: meaning it's an app based variable like Workbook, worksheet, etc... not the right language, sorry

Comment: `Cell` is not a part of the Excel object model. `Cells` is, but `Cell` is not. Regardless, you need a variable, so add `Dim Cell As Range` and your troubles will be solved.